# Why does the child element of a div change the margin between the body and the html?

Tags: html, css

Why does adding the 60px margin to the *p* tag inside the body, also change the placement of the *div* with the class* *header*. Shouldn't a fixed position element be unaffected by the other elements on the page?

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
}
.left {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

<body>
  <div class="header">
      Exercise 2.4
  </div>
  <p class="left">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sed magna vitae lorem hendrerit posuere. Nullam ut ex ipsum. Cras volutpat augue in metus tempus ultricies sit amet nec lacus.
  </p>
</body>
```

If I remove the class *left* from the p tag, the spacing between the body and the html goes down to 8 pixels as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)!

If you have two nested elements with top margins, the margin gets shared between them. That is, both elements get the same value for the margin.

Normally, this will only affect the first child element in the parent, but in this case the browser will make an exception for you because the first element has `position:fixed`, so it will take the second element.

Solution: give `.left` a padding instead of a margin.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
}
.left {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
      Exercise 2.4
  </div>
  <p class="left">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sed magna vitae lorem hendrerit posuere. Nullam ut ex ipsum. Cras volutpat augue in metus tempus ultricies sit amet nec lacus.
  </p>
```

Comment: Why would the placement of a fixed element be affected by the margin of it's sibling? Don't fixed elements get positioned relative to the browser window not the current box?

Comment: @effervescent-phantom Only if you specify `left` and `top`! If you don't, the element will be displayed in the position it would normally be displayed if you hadn't changed `position`. (It works like this for `position:absolute` too.)